Spring Boot Properties Files
In my Spring Boot application, I have two properties files. One is located in src/main/resources/application.properties and the other properties file is in src/test/resources/application.properties.
Whenever I add a property to the main property file, I also have to add it to the test property file or the app will not boot.
Is there a way to make the main application.properties automatically apply to the test context so that I can only override the properties which are different for the test context?
For the test context, the only real different properties are for the database connection and the rest of the properties should be the same as the main context.
I did try creating a src/main/resources/application-test.properties and deleting the src/test/resources/application.properties but the app would not start with an error about properties not being found.

try removing the test/resources folder

When I remove the test/resources folder, the tests are unable to connect to the test database (which is different from the main db). If I put the test db config in application-test.properties, it is ignored. The main app uses JNDI and the tests do not.

it depends on whether ur using profiles, see spring external config

I'm currently not trying to use profiles. The command I run is mvn clean package - if I add -DskipTests the problem goes away though.

i get the impression(from a quick pass through that help doc) props files are all-or-nothing inside them...that why the profiles files exist...i might have missed something though

You would usually have an application.properties in main and an application-test.properties in test, then run the Spring integration tests with profile test.

The application.properties should automatically get applied in you @SpringBootTest. You can however explicitly add them to the test class with @TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
